# Renaming index gives error Explicit @objtype id not recognised

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to rename an index and getting an error:

> Error: Explicit @objtype 'idx_FinData20' is unrecognized.

I can see both the table and index exist. Then what is the problem

```
     IF ( EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND  TABLE_NAME ='FinData2000_1_old'))
     BEGIN

     EXEC sp_rename  'FinData2000_1_old.idx_FinData2000_1' , 'idx_FinData2000_1', 'idx_FinData20 00_1_old'

     end
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: I have tagged now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First - your syntax is wrong. You need only two arguments, first should be `table_name.old_name` and second one is just `new name`. 
Second - you have an extra space in your new index name which breaks the script.

```
EXEC sp_rename 'FinData2000_1_old.idx_FinData2000_1' , 'idx_FinData2000_1_old'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your were using the wrong syntax for `SP_RENAME`, by default, it accepts two inputs, the 1st one is `old name`, the 2nd one is `new name`, if you would specify the 3rd one(optional and for diffing the objects), that should be the `object name`.

I am not sure what is the correct case for you, but as an example, you can try this:

`EXEC SP_RENAME 'INDEX_OLD_NAME', 'INDEX_NEW_NAME', 'INDEX'`

As an additional notes: doing the `rename` will have potential risk of breaking the remaining process.

Answer (score 0):

learn.microsoft.com specifies that @ObjType can only have one of the following values.

Column 
Database 
Index 
Object 
Statistics (SQL Server 2012 (11.x) and later and Azure SQL Database.)
UserDataType

There are internal processes for renaming tables and views that handle the table and view references for @ObjType automatically.  So if you're renaming tables/views, leave off @ObjType since the engine is smart enough to figure it out on its own.

Also make sure to include the schema (even if its just dbo so it becomes second nature to you to include it in the future...) in @ObjName since there may be the same named tables in different schemas.

It is also worthy to note that once you rename a table, any indexes you made on the old table are automatically updated to reference the new table name that you just updated it to.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally worked out that some objects need to be quoted.  This can be done with the `QUOTENAME()` function.

For example, I have a primary key constraint created by EF6 named `PK_dbo.SafetyDataSheets`.

To rename this constraint name the following can be used:

```sql
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.' + QUOTENAME(`PK_dbo.SafetyDataSheets`), 'PK_SafetyDataSheets'
```